# Import bookmarks from Firefox to Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I want to import bookmarks from Firefox into Microsoft Edge however I only see the option to import book marks from IE and Chrome.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can only import bookmarks from IE and Chrome.  The workaround is as follows:

- first export the bookmark as a HTML file in Firefox.  Go to "Import and Backup" and click to choose "Export Bookmarks to HTML"
- then import this HTML bookmark file to either IE or Chrome.

  In IE, choose "Import and Export" and select "import from a file" option

  In Chrome, go to "bookmark manager", under "Organize" chose "Import bookmarks from HTML file" option
- Now, you are ready to import the bookmark from IE or Chrome to Edge by using the "Import Favorites" under "Favorites settings".

Answer (score 0):

haven't verified this but it looks promising:

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-import-bookmarks-into-edge/

Perhaps you could use IE or Chrome as a go-between if Firefox doesn't show up in the list and there's no way to browse to it.